# Allowing a specific user to bypass reviewers

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible for a specific user to bypass the review policies of a pull request?

For my specific scenario I am running NuKeeper on a pipeline and my Build Service user is successfully creating a pull request, but I'd like any PRs raised by this user to automatically bypass the required reviewers (but still go through the checks e.g. my build and test stage) - Is this possible?

The only other workaround I could think of would be to have a scheduled "master" pipeline which iterates over my repos and just merges all open pull requests from that particular user.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a specific user to bypass the review policies of a pull request?

You could add a account with higher permission, `set Bypass policies when completing pull requests` as `Allow`:

[image]

When we use this account to create a PR, this account can complete the PR directly without the approval of the reviewer.

Besides, there are a couple of ways to set up bypassing depending on how broadly you want to give someone rights to bypass. We are going to start with the narrower option which is allowing bypass for an **individual branch** or we could set it at **the repo level**.

You could check the document [Azure DevOps Repos: Bypass Branch Policies](https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-repos-bypass-branch-policies/) for some more details.

Comment: That's not quite what I want it to do - I want it to automatically merge the PR if that particular user raises one.